# Purchased a rigged character, but can't vertex paint

Tags: materials, texture-painting, color, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

I purchased a royalty free rigged hamster from TurboSquid but the colors are wrong and don't fully match the colors on my free downloaded hamster from TurboSquid. I tried to create a New Material to Vertex Paint on some white to the hamster's face and belly, but I think there may be an issue preventing me from doing this as the existing material doesn't show up in the Nodes and the New Material isn't affecting the existing coloring.

Here's the naming of that material (aiStandard?)

[image: Material page]

I want to use this hamster in a clip on my Demo Reel, but I want the two hamsters to basically match in color. The spacesuit won't come off the free hamster, so I purchased the normal hamster w/o a spacesuit for the non-space scenes.

Hoping anyone can help me just make this minor color adjustment to keep basic consistency in my scenes. TurboSquid doesn't allow contact with modelers or I would just ask him/her to re-create the space hamster without its suit.
[image: Hamster Issue Non-Paint]

**EQUIPMENT / SOFTWARE:**

[image: Computer Specs]

**Working with Blender v2.83**

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Looks like you are seeing the selected material in the node editor but you have two other materials there that also would need the same Vcol attribute input to see vertex paint. Perhaps you need to delete the materials and just create a new one with the vcol attribute input.

Comment: Thank you Craig! Found out I just had to put 'Use Nodes' when on those materials and they showed up in the Shading tab and I was able to manipulate them. I used the Vertex Group assignment to pick areas I wanted brown or white and now just need to refine and will have the whole hamster ready for the Demo Reel! Yay!! YOU ROCK!!